# hybrid function into one-line form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I came across a non-homogeneous ODE with the non-homogeneous term $g(t)$ defined by a few functions like this one below:
$$g(t)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
f_1(t), & 0\leq t<a\\ 
f_2(t), & a\leq t<b\\ 
\vdots\\ 
f_n(t), & t \geq n
\end{matrix}\right.$$
This is actually the general case which I want to translate into a one-line piece-wise form.
How could this be done?

Answer (score 1):

What about
$$g(t)=\sum_{i=1}^nf_n(t)\left(H(t-a_{n-1})-H(t-a_n)\right),$$
where $H(t)$ is the Heaviside step function ?